# can't assign to array -vba

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I'm trying implement the next code and get the error -

> cant assign to array

Where is the error ? Note that if i type `Dim arrf() As Variant` instead of `Dim arrf(5) As Variant` I get error -

> type mismatch

```
Public Function calc(ByVal value As Integer, ByVal num As Integer) As Variant()

Dim arr(5) As Variant
Dim x As Double

If value >= num Then
    x = value - Application.RoundDown(value / num, 0) * num
    arr(0) = x
    arr(1) = num - arr(0)
    arr(2) = Application.RoundUp(value / num, 0)
    arr(3) = 1
    arr(4) = Application.RoundDown(value / num, 0)
    arr(5) = 1
Else
    x = num - Application.RoundDown(num / value, 0) * value
    arr(0) = x
    arr(1) = value - arr(0)
    arr(2) = Application.RoundUp(num / value, 0)
    arr(3) = 1
    arr(4) = Application.RoundDown(num / value, 0)
    arr(5) = 1
    calc = arr
End If

End Function


Sub cellsfunc()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

Dim arrf(5) As Variant

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For counter = 2 To lastrow Step 2
    arrf = calc(Cells(4, counter), Cells(4, counter + 1))
Next counter

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

thanks ahead to all helpers

Comment: you need to add a condition where `num` equals 0, otherwise you will get an error in the line `x = value - Application.RoundDown(value / num, 0) * num` since you are trying to devide be zero

Comment: to see where the error is, select Break In Class Module in the General Options http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx

Answer (score 16):

You have `arrf` declared as a *fixed size* array:

```
Dim arrf(5) As Variant
```

An array returning function can't return a fixed size array - only a dynamic one.  You just need to declare it as a dynamic array:

```
Dim arrf() As Variant
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue in your function `calc()` : it only returns a value when it goes through the `else`, and not the `if`

It should probably be this:

```
Public Function calc(ByVal value As Integer, ByVal num As Integer) As Variant()

  Dim arr(5) As Variant
  Dim x As Double
  If value >= num Then
    x = value - Application.RoundDown(value / num, 0) * num
    arr(0) = x
    arr(1) = num - arr(0)
    arr(2) = Application.RoundUp(value / num, 0)
    arr(3) = 1
    arr(4) = Application.RoundDown(value / num, 0)
    arr(5) = 1
  Else
     x = num - Application.RoundDown(num / value, 0) * value
    arr(0) = x
    arr(1) = value - arr(0)
    arr(2) = Application.RoundUp(num / value, 0)
    arr(3) = 1
    arr(4) = Application.RoundDown(num / value, 0)
    arr(5) = 1
  End If
  calc = arr ' <------- THIS
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a typed array in VBA script always use `ReDim..` size initialization. You may use a typed array in a dictionary value or everywhere like a regular variable.

```
Public Function readData(ws As Worksheet, arr As Scripting.Dictionary) As Boolean
  Dim iRow as long 
  Dim key as String 
  Dim sVal() As String
  ReDim sVal(0 to 1) as String 

  For iRow=2 to 1000
    key = ws.cells(iRow,1)
    sVal(0) = ws.Cells(iRow, 5)
    sVal(1) = ws.Cells(iRow, 6)
    call arr.Add(key, sVal)
  Next
  readData=true 
End Function

Public Function writeData(ws As Worksheet, arr As Scripting.Dictionary) As Long
  Dim iRow as long 
  Dim key as String 
  Dim sVal() As String
  ReDim sVal(0 to 1) as String 

  For iRow=2 to 1000
    key = ws.cells(iRow,1)
    If arr.Exists(key) then
      sVal = arr.Item(key)
      ws.Cells(iRow, 5) = sVal(0)
      ws.Cells(iRow, 6) = sVal(1)
    End If
  Next
  writeData=true 
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare `aarf` as a regular variant not an array.  The VBA will convert it for you.

`Dim arrf As Variant`