# Can't assign to array error in trying to access an array returned by an Excel VBA User Defined Function

Tags: arrays, excel, user-defined-functions

I'd very much appreciate someone's help with this as it is driving me nuts!

I'm simply trying to generate an array of 12 monthly periods using the user-supplied period as a reference point. The UDF is working correctly as I've tested (within the UDF itself) that the array it returns contains the expected values. I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub TestPeriods()
Dim CurrentPeriod As Long
Dim arrPeriods(1 To 12) As Variant

CurrentPeriod = 201901
arrPeriods = GeneratePeriods(CurrentPeriod) 'Error on this line

End Sub

Function GeneratePeriods(CurrentPeriod As Long) As Variant

Dim CurrentPeriodMonth As Integer, PeriodSet(1 To 12) As Variant
Dim CurrentYear As Integer, PriorYear As Integer
CurrentPeriodMonth = CurrentPeriod Mod 100
CurrentYear = (CurrentPeriod - (CurrentPeriod Mod 100)) / 100
PriorYear = CurrentYear - 1

If CurrentPeriodMonth < 12 Then
    For i = 1 To CurrentPeriodMonth
        PeriodSet(i) = CLng(CurrentYear) * 100 + i
    Next i

    For i = CurrentPeriodMonth + 1 To 12
        PeriodSet(i) = CLng(PriorYear) * 100 + i
    Next i

Else
    For i = CurrentPeriodMonth To 12
        PeriodSet(i) = CLng(CurrentYear) * 100 + i
    Next i
End If

GeneratePeriods = PeriodSet

End Function
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557858/cant-assign-to-array-vba

Comment: @SJR many thanks for your help. That post has helped me understand that in this I should ve declared a dynamic array.

Comment: My pleasure Albert.