Unable to assign the returned data from a function to an array. "Compile error: Can't assign to array"
Here's a minimum version that produces the error. I try to assign the returned data from the function TestFunction to the array TestArray.
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim TestArray(1 To 3) As Long
    TestArray = TestFunction()
End Sub


Function TestFunction() As Long()

    Dim Value1 As Long
    Dim Value2 As Long
    Dim Value3 As Long
    
    '-----------------
    '
    ' Some code that calculates the three values
    '
    '-----------------
    
    
    'Assign the three values to the returned array
    TestFunction(1) = Value1
    TestFunction(2) = Value2
    TestFunction(3) = Value3
    
End Function

I get the error "Compile error: Can't assign to array" at the line TestArray = TestFunction()
Anyone have an idea why?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557858/cant-assign-to-array-vba

This question is similar to: can't assign to array -vba. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In addition to the comments about fixed size arrays, you should also be aware that whilst TestFuntion has a declared retunr type of a dynamic array of Long(), you can't assign to that dynamic array until you dimension it with redim statement, e.g. Redim TestFunction(1 to 3).  YOu should also be aware that using the function name return value as a variable in your method makes for difficult to read code.

Thanks for the comments. I guess the question you linked have the same problem. How do I solve this situation? I have few points on this site and I'm close to being banned because my questions are not clear enough. I don't try to write unclear questions, I'm learning all the time how to write better questions. This is my best question to date I would say. Should I delete it? Or how do I resolve this without losing more points?

You have two issues here:
The first (that is causing the compiler error "Can't assign to array") is that  TestArray (in the calling Test sub) is a static array - an array that has already a fixed size and the memory is already assigned to it. In VBA, you can't assign a different array to to a static array.
So changing the definition to a dynamic array will do the trick:
Sub Test()
    Dim TestArray() As Long
    ' Also possible: 
    ' Dim TestArray As Variant
    ' But not:
    ' Dim TestArray() As Variant

    TestArray = TestFunction()
End Sub

Once this is fixed, you will face another compiler error inside your function, when you try to assign the first value. It reads "Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return an variant or object". This comes from the fact that for the VBA compiler, TestFunction(1) looks like a (recursive) function call to TestFunction, not as an assignment to an array.
The fix is to use a variable to create the array and assign it as function value at the end:
Function TestFunction() As Long()
    (...)
    Dim result(1 To 3) As Long
    'Assign the three values to the returned array
     result(1) = Value1
     result(2) = Value2
     result(3) = Value3
  
     TestFunction = result
End Function

Note that it's probably better to use the result array already in the calculation part (instead of the 3 Value-variables)
